# How do I grant users access to specific APIs with IdentityServer4?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

I'm building a new security token service (running IdentityServer4 on ASP.NET Core), and need to give users logging in to frontend applications access to certain APIs only.

So far, I'm able to have users log in to a JS client, and get authorized/authenticated with access to the APIs configured as allowed scopes on the token service for that specific JS client.

What I wish to do, is configure each user to only have access to certian APIs - not neccessarily all the APIs in the allowed scopes.

I'm new to this, so I'm not even sure if I'm asking the right question. But, I hope it's understandable still and will happily answer any question.

---

**How I define my user in token service:**

```
new TestUser
{
    SubjectId = "05624",
    Username = "asd",
    Password = "asd",
    Claims = new []
    {
        new Claim("name", "My Name"),
        new Claim("email", "myname@email.net")
    }
}
```

---

**How I define my client in token service:**

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "js-demo"
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
    AllowedScopes = 
    { 
        "openid", 
        "api_1",
        "api_2"
    },
    AllowedCorsOrigins = { "http://localhost:5000" },
    RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5000/callback.html" },
    PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5000/index.html" },
    RequirePkce = true,
    RequireClientSecret = false,
    AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true
}
```

---

**How I define my API resourcess in token service:**

```
new List<ApiResource>
{
    new ApiResource("api_1"),
    new ApiResource("api_2")
};
```

---

**How I define my frontend client:**

```
var config = {
    client_id: "js-demo",
    response_type: "code",
    scope: "openid api_1 api_2",
    authority: "http://localhost:9999",
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:5000/callback.html",
    post_logout_redirect_uri: "http://localhost:5000/index.html"
};
```

Comment: That's user authorization, which doesn't have to be implemented at IdentityServer level and is in fact also [not recommended there](https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/#li-comment-131079). Their authorization solution is the [PolicyServer](https://policyserver.io/). And there are other authorization solutions you can use, like [resource-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased)

Comment: Thanks! One thing I found though, is that I can set each user's consent to application access. I found this using the quickstart examples from IdentityServer4's GitHub. Wouldn't that be the same as granting a user access to specific API resources?

Comment: The client makes requests on behalf of the user, but only if the user has given consent (which is configurable). Meaning that the user can deny the client access to a certain resource. This puts the user in control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IdentityServer is not meant to do that. It grants an application permission to use the identity of the user, not a user permission to use the application.

If you're only building a simple system, you could assign users `role` claims, and make policies in your application that allows / forbids users based on their roles. But as your permission logic will keep growing this will become hard to manage.

Have a look at PolicyServer, they have a nice presentation about the issue you're having.
https://policyserver.io/

Comment: Thank you. As I commented above though, I just found that using the quickstart examples from IdentityServer4's GitHub - I can allow consents for the user logging in, and select which API resources I wish to consent. Isn't this the same as allowing a user to access only certain APIs?

Comment: That's what I meant by the first sentence. :) It's the user permitting an application to have access to their data. So you can let your Calendar to use your Contacts. (API Resource), or you can let your Calendar to access your birthday (Identity Resource).

Comment: What you can't do is limit what user has access to what API, that's authorisation, not authentication, which is not part of the scope of IdentityServer4. Again you can do this via claims assigned to the user, but it's not advised.

Comment: Oh, I see - I think I'm getting it now. Thanks again! Investigating PolicyServer further and it's starting to make definite sense.

Comment: It is a tough one.. glad I could help. :)